# How to send String JMX metrics?

Tags: jmx, datadog

I am using a Java application that is sending metrics trough JMX with the following config :

```
instances:
  - host: localhost
    port: 9999
    conf:
      - include:
          domain: 'debezium.postgres'
```

Most of the metrics are sent without any issue, however there are some metrics that are missing in the dashboard.

Agent logs :

```
2022-03-10 05:14:22 GMT | JMX | WARN | JmxAttribute | Unable to get metrics from debezium.postgres:type=connector-metrics,context=snapshot,server=xxxx - ChunkId: java.lang.NumberFormatException
2022-03-10 05:14:22 GMT | JMX | WARN | JmxAttribute | Unable to get metrics from debezium.postgres:type=connector-metrics,context=snapshot,server=xxxx - ChunkFrom: java.lang.NumberFormatException
2022-03-10 05:14:22 GMT | JMX | WARN | JmxAttribute | Unable to get metrics from debezium.postgres:type=connector-metrics,context=snapshot,server=xxxx - ChunkTo: java.lang.NumberFormatException
2022-03-10 05:14:22 GMT | JMX | WARN | JmxAttribute | Unable to get metrics from debezium.postgres:type=connector-metrics,context=snapshot,server=xxxx - TableFrom: java.lang.NumberFormatException
2022-03-10 05:14:22 GMT | JMX | WARN | JmxAttribute | Unable to get metrics from debezium.postgres:type=connector-metrics,context=snapshot,server=xxxx - TableTo: java.lang.NumberFormatException
2022-03-10 05:14:22 GMT | JMX | WARN | JmxAttribute | Unable to get metrics from debezium.postgres:type=connector-metrics,context=snapshot,server=xxxx - LastEvent: java.lang.NumberFormatException
2022-03-10 05:14:22 GMT | JMX | WARN | JmxAttribute | Unable to get metrics from debezium.postgres:type=connector-metrics,context=streaming,server=xxxx - SourceEventPosition: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "lsn"
2022-03-10 05:14:22 GMT | JMX | WARN | JmxAttribute | Unable to get metrics from debezium.postgres:type=connector-metrics,context=streaming,server=xxxx - LastEvent: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "position: {lsn: 949416252032}, key: {"id" : "89845"}"
```

Those metrics are sent as `String`, but it seems that Datadog can only understand `Integer` type metrics ...

Is there a way to configure the agent to sent string metrics ?

Comment: hmm, what exactly does it mean for a metric to be a string? is that more like a status value? an event?

Comment: @stephenlechner Yes it's more like an event, for instance there's a metric named LastEvent where the values sent are in Json format

Comment: If you have JSON it should be decomposed until you have numbers that can be sent as metrics, or your data should be stored as a log event rather than a metric. `LastEvent` sounds like a log event to me - a thing that happened at a point in time, rather than a thing meant to be compared with the same thing at other points in time

Comment: I face the same issue when using the Debezium MySQL connector. It seems Datadog only captured numerics metrics and we cannot get JSON or UUID values.